# Does $\frac{1}{2}\log{x} + 1\log{x/4} + 2\log{x/16} + 4\log{x/64} + 8\log{x/256} + ...+ $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{1}{2}\log{x} + 1\log{\frac{x}{4}} + 2\log{\frac{x}{16}} + 4\log{\frac{x}{64}} + 8\log{\frac{x}{256}} + ...+  $

Does the above series converge? What if I bound the number of terms to $N = \log_{4}(x)$ ? Could one then obtain a closed form expression?

I believe it is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$, though I am not sure of this nor have I any idea how to prove it.

EDIT: As one person correctly pointed out, the series diverges if no bound is imposed on $N$. But if $N = \log_{4}(x)$, it remains unclear what the sum converges to?

Answer (score 4):

One can obtain an explicit expression for the sum since it is just a geometric series in disguise. You can write

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^N 2^{n-1}\log \frac{x}{2^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^N (2^{n-1}\log x-n2^n\log 2)=(2^N-1)\log x-2\log 2[1+(N-1)2^N]$$

The second sum can be obtained by observing

$$\sum_{n=0}^N n x^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n=\frac{(N+1)x^N}{x-1}-\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

For $N=\log_4(x)$, the function can be evaluated explicitly:

$$S=2\log2(\sqrt{x}-1)-\log x=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$$

and is indeed dominated by $\sqrt{x}$ for large values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will diverge (for all positive x), as the terms being logged get arbitrarily small, so the logged terms get arbitrarily large (and negative).

If the number of terms is limited to log(x) terms then the (finite) series will converge for any positive x, as each term is finite, and there are a finite number of terms.

Comment: Excellent observation. If I bound the number of terms $N = \log_{4}(x))$ then the term being logged will never go below 1.  In such a case, can one obtain a bound on the finite sum?